# how to get Emacs org-mode done statistics to filter up through non-todo headings?

Tags: emacs, org-mode

How do I get org-mode DONE statistics to filter up through non-todo headings and update the statistics cookie?

I have an org-mode file that looks like this:

```
* <2013-03-06 Wed> [0%]
** work
*** training
**** TODO email Anne
**** DONE call Raymond
*** reports
**** DONE collect research
**** DONE compile data
*** white papers
**** TODO collect client files
*** sales
**** DONE email Wendy                         
** housekeeping
*** DONE go to post office!
```

The parent headings are not TODO tasks; they're conceptual categories.

I want org-mode to calculate the % done statistics as I mark tasks DONE.

I tried setting `org-hierarchical-todo-statistics` to `t` but that didn't help.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You've set the variable backwards, try:

```lisp
(setq org-hierarchical-todo-statistics nil)
```

If you only want it to have effect on certain (a single) tree, use the property `:COOKIE_DATA: recursive`

From the variable definition:

```
org-hierarchical-todo-statistics is a variable defined in `org.el'.
Its value is nil
Original value was t

Documentation:
Non-nil means TODO statistics covers just direct children.
When nil, all entries in the subtree are considered.
This has only an effect if `org-provide-todo-statistics' is set.
To set this to nil for only a single subtree, use a COOKIE_DATA
property and include the word "recursive" into the value.
```

Answer (score 3):

Doing a

```
(setq org-hierarchical-todo-statistics nil)
```

works for me! You can also set the COOKIE_DATA property to recursive:

```
* <2013-03-06 Wed> [71%]
  :PROPERTIES:
  :COOKIE_DATA: recursive
  :END:
** work
*** training
**** TODO email Anne
**** DONE call Raymond
*** reports
**** DONE collect research
**** DONE compile data
*** white papers
**** TODO collect client files
*** sales
**** DONE email Wendy
** housekeeping
*** DONE go to post office!
```